# Plotting timeseries plot from structure array in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, plot, data-structures, time-series

I have downloaded stock prices data for each company in the S&P500 (over the last 5 years) and stored them in a structure array called `stocks_adj_close` (see code).

I would like to perform some data analysis such as plotting, for example I would like to plot all fives stocks on the same graph.

```
load('SP500stocks.mat'); %load data from a previously saved workspace

fields ={'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume'}; %create a variable fields

stocks_adj_close = rmfield(stocks, fields); % removes the fields mentionned here above

struct2csv(stocks_adj_close, 'SP500 Adjusted Stocks Prices (2000-20019).csv');
```

Comment: How exactly does your structure look like? What problems do you have accessing the data from the structure to plot it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You may want to look up [`plot()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html). You may need the `hold on` command. Otherwise, please use self-help more on plot manipulation in Matlab and, after that, feel free to come back with specific questions.